# Data binding in Kendo grid popup window with MultiSelect widget

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which uses custom template for editing inside popup window.

```
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                    .TemplateName("EditForm")
                    .Window(wnd => wnd.Title("New form")
                       .Name("EditFormWindow")
                    .Draggable(true)
                    .Modal(true)
```

The template contains several Kendo dropdowns, which are cascaded from each other.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("FormGroupId")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
          .OptionLabel("Select form group...")
          .DataTextField("Name")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Route(RouteConfig.GetFormGroupNames.Name)).ServerFiltering(true))
                          .Events(events =>
                              {
                                  events.Cascade("onFormGroupChange");
                                  events.Change("onFormGroupChange");
                              })
          )
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("Schema")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
          .OptionLabel("Select schema...")
          .DataTextField("SchemaName")
          .DataValueField("SchemaName")
          .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Route(RouteConfig.FilterFormSchemas.Name).Data("filterSchemas")).ServerFiltering(true))
          .Enable(false)
          .AutoBind(false)
          .CascadeFrom("FormGroupId")
          )
</div>
```

And they work fine, but right now I need to add MultiSelect widget to this template, which doesn't support cascading out of the box.

So I added such code:

```
<input id="Sectors" name="Sectors" disabled="disabled" />

    var sectors;
    var formGroupParametersDataSource;

    var sectorsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: []
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        formGroupParametersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: "@Url.RouteUrl(RouteConfig.GetFormGroupParameters.Name)"
            },
            change: function() {
                var data = this.data()[0].Sectors.toJSON();
                sectorsDataSource.data(data);
            }
        });

        sectors = $("#Sectors").kendoMultiSelect({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField: "Key",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            optionLabel: "Select form sectors...",
            dataSource: sectorsDataSource,
        }).data("kendoMultiSelect");

    });

    function onFormGroupChange(e) {        
        var value = this.value();
        if (value) {
            formGroupParametersDataSource.one("change", function () {
                sectors.current(null);
            }).filter({
                field: "Id",
                operator: "eq",
                value: value
            });

            sectors.enable();
            sectors.refresh();
        } else {
            sectors.enable(false);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am filtering the datasource each time I changed FormGroupId dropdown setting the data of Sectors property inside the view model to the newly created sectorsDataSource.

That works fine for new row in the grid. The problem comes when I try to edit the row, then even if the Sectors property in the viewmodel has values they are not bound to the multiselect widget.

Any suggestions or help?